# NodeJs: How can I see the log of a NodeJs server running by PM2 in a EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pm2

Right now I'm running a NodeJs server on  AWS EC2 shell with PM2. I've tried to obtain logs of PM2, but the logs are not as expected since are from the PM2 service itself and not the instance of Node. I've failed to found any documentation for this on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo pm2 list
```

This will display the list of apps running via pm2. You can then stream  logs for any of those apps using

```
sudo pm2 logs <id>
```

or

```
sudo pm2 logs <app name>
```

These are not pm2 service logs but rather the logs created by your node app.

Answer (score 1):

Might be as simple as:

```
pm2 logs
```

Read "Displaying logs in realtime" http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/.

Or, you see the actual logs in `$HOME/.pm2`: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Answer (score 0):

if you write this

```
pm2 logs
```

it gives you all the logs of the server and

if you want specific log for particular server 
write this

```
pm2 logs <id>
```